# block a rundeck node from arbitrary cloud and non-cloud resource discovery?

Tags: rundeck

Is there a way to block arbitrary nodes being reported/discovered/red-status in rundeck? With all the sources feeding in (GCP plugin, resources.xml, etc.) I have often found a job status which applies to "all" is red since the individual instance isn't yet configured, giving a red status to the job.

Would be great if there were a way to do an easy block from the GUI and CLI for all resources for the given node.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom node-filters rules based on nodes status using health check status (also you can filter by name, tags, ip address, regex, etc). Take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/05-nodes.html#node-filtering) (at "Saving filters" section you've a good example).

Answer (score 0):

Do a .*hostnamepattern.* in the exclude filter in the job and hit Save.

Simplify-simplify-simplify.